# Error on didselect tableview on SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, swrevealviewcontroller

when i worked with slide out menu  using `SWRevealViewController` class ,it works correctly in iphone simulator.But when i tried to run in the iphone 5 device for testing,while selecting the menu button it shows the slide out menu properly, but unfortunately,while selecting the cells ,it crashes and shows the following error.but no such errors in simulator.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    indexPath = [[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (indexPath.row==0) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"home" sender:indexPath];

    }
  else if (indexPath.row==1) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"cartme" sender:indexPath];

    }
   else {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"changelocation" sender:indexPath];

    }
}
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SWRevealViewControllerSegue
>   setDestinationContainmentContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x175c5f90'

please help me.

Comment: Share the code of `didSelectRowForIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem, I fixed it by changing segue type to "Custom" instead of "Push"

Answer (score 0):

Add more information based on [this iOS open source codes](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStoryboardPushSegueTemplate.h).

It is obvious, that `setDestinationContainmentContext` is a method for `push` segue. So, the custom segue should choose `Custom` segue type, not `Push`.

Subclass from `UIStoryboardSegue` has no such method, so it crashes.

```
/* Generated by RuntimeBrowser
   Image: /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
 */

@interface UIStoryboardPushSegueTemplate : UIStoryboardSegueTemplate {
    int  _destinationContainmentContext;
    int  _splitViewControllerIndex;
}

@property (nonatomic) int destinationContainmentContext;
@property (nonatomic) int splitViewControllerIndex;

- (int)destinationContainmentContext;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (id)initWithCoder:(id)arg1;
- (id /* block */)newDefaultPerformHandlerForSegue:(id)arg1;
- (void)setDestinationContainmentContext:(int)arg1;
- (void)setSplitViewControllerIndex:(int)arg1;
- (int)splitViewControllerIndex;

@end
```